# How to Apply a Glassmorphism Effect to an Image Using Jetpack Compose and Coil?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a project using Jetpack Compose, and I want to apply a blur effect to an image. I plan to apply a blurred background to an image fetched from the internet.

The library I'm using is Coil. My goal is to design a Glassmorphism card. I want to add a semi-transparent, blurred background over an image and place text or other components on this blurred area, just like in the image below.

[image]

How can I achieve this kind of design using Jetpack Compose and Coil? Is there any helpful code snippet or documentation?

Comment: Also looking for this...
I have a PagerAdapter with AsyncImage and want to put a blurred (glassmorphism card) on it...

Answer (score 0):

In order to create glassmorphism card, you could set an alpha (40%) transparent Card and apply a blur effect with this library:
https://github.com/skydoves/Cloudy